# Using a function in Python to return a substring

Tags: python, python-3.x, substring

I have a feeling my question is pretty basic, as I am a first semester computer science student.

I have been asked to return the **substring formed before a digit in a string** similar to `"abcd5efgh"`. The idea is to use a function to give me `"abcd"`. I think I need to use `.isdigit`, but I'm not sure how to turn it into a function. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4):

It could be done with regexp, but if you already discovered `isdigit`, why not use it in this case?

You can modify the last `return s` line to return something else if no digit is found:

```
def string_before_digit(s):
    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        if c.isdigit():
            return s[:i]
    return s # no digit found

print(string_before_digit("abcd5efgh"))
```

Comment: I just tried this and I got a syntax error with string_before_digit highlighted. Am I missing something?

Comment: @posthumana You are using Python 3, use `print(...)` instead of `print...`

Comment: Awesome! I should've known. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I am also currently a student and this is how i would approch this problem:
*For my school we are not allowed to use built in function like that in python :/

```
     def parse(string):
       newstring = ""
       for i in string:
          if i >= "0" and i <= "9":
             break
          else:
             newstring += i
       print newstring #Can use return if your needing it in another function

     parse("abcd5efgh")
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Consider the more idiomatic `if '0' <= i <= '9':` instead of `if i >= "0" and i <= "9":`

Answer (score 1):

A functional approach :)

```
>>> from itertools import compress, count, imap
>>> text = "abcd5efgh"
>>> text[:next(compress(count(), imap(str.isdigit, text)), len(text))]
'abcd'
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is below will give you the first non digit part by using regular expression.

```
import re
myPattern=re.compile('[a-zA-Z]*')
firstNonDigitPart=myPattern.match('abcd5efgh')
firstNonDigitPart.group()
>>> 'abcd'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not allowed to use regexes, maybe because they told you to do it explicitly by hand, you can do it like this:

```
def digit_index(s):
    """Helper function."""
    # next(..., -1) asks the given iterator for the next value and returns -1 if there is none.
    # This iterator gives the index n of the first "true-giving" element of the asked generator expression. True-giving is any character which is a digit.
    return next(
        (n for n, i in enumerate(i.isdigit() for i in "abc123") if i),
        -1)

def before_digit(s):
    di = digit_index(s)
    if di == -1: return s
    return s[:di]
```

should give you your wanted result.

Comment: instead of `-1` you could return `len(s)`

Comment: @jamylak Right, but -1 makes the function be more compatible with other search functions and usable in other contexts. Programming in a re-usable way is also an important aspect of learning to program...

Comment: You are already slicing it, assuming it's a list/string, so it's not very reusable right now

Answer (score 0):

A quite simple one-liner, using [`isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) :)

```
>>> s = 'abcd5efgh'
>>> s[:[i for i, j in enumerate([_ for _ in s]) if j.isdigit()][0]]
'abcd'
```

Answer (score 0):

An itertools approach:

```
>>> from itertools import takewhile
>>> s="abcd5efgh"
>>> ''.join(takewhile(lambda x: not x.isdigit(), s))
'abcd'
```